# Spring Security antMatchers permitAll not working

Tags: spring-mvc, kotlin, spring-security

Spring security antMatcher permitAll not working as expected.

I am running Spring boot application with kotlin
When I am trying to access

`/service-status/v1/task/status`

I have added this url in ant matcher permit all in bellow code

its giving me unauthorized error

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(val authenticationEntryPoint: AuthenticationEntryPoint) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("pass"))
                .authorities("ROLE_USER")
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
        http?.csrf()?.disable()
                ?.authorizeRequests()
                ?.antMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/service-status/v1/task/status",
                        "/*.html",
                        "/*.js",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/configuration/**",
                        "/v2/**",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/**/*.js")?.permitAll()
                ?.anyRequest()?.authenticated()
                ?.and()
                ?.httpBasic()
                ?.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
    }


    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }


}
```

getting error as following

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-05-09T08:37:25.976+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/service-status/v1/task/status"
}
```

Authentication entry point

```
@Component
class AuthenticationEntryPoint : BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint(){
    override fun commence(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?, authException: AuthenticationException?) {
        response?.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=$realmName")
        response?.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED
        response?.writer?.println("HTTP Status 401 - " + authException?.message)
    }

    override fun afterPropertiesSet() {
        realmName = "service-status"
        super.afterPropertiesSet()
    }
}
```

How to fix this???

Comment: Did you send HTTP `Authentication` header in your request? Do you use Spring Boot?

Comment: It seems to me that the order of the calls are important, maybe you can invert the antMatcher("").permitAll and the anyRequest().authenticated(). And you can put the HttpSecurity parameter as non nullable.

Comment: I am using spring boot, I am not sending any header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haved added bellow two line now its working

```
.antMatchers("/service-status/v1/task/status").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/service-status/v1/task/status/**").permitAll()
```

Full form

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/",
                        "/csrf",
                        "/service-status/v1/task/status",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/*.html",
                        "/*.js",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/configuration/**",
                        "/v2/**",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/**/*.js"
                ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/service-status/v1/task/status").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/service-status/v1/task/status/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        http.headers().cacheControl();
    }
```